# Create a virtual surface with Aruco

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I'm currently working on an Python Project using Aruco marker. I have one marker on the top left side of my table and i now want to create a rectangle from that position with fixed lengths. For example my working space out from the aruco marker should be 0,1m height and 0,3m width. I already calibrated my camera so i can measure distance and depth. I hope the picture can describe what i wanted to do: [image]

So i need to calculate the position of the other 3 points. Depending on the rotation of the aruco marker. Is there a openCV function who could help me with that? Or any other ideas?

Thank you very much <3

Comment: define those 3d points in the marker's coordinate frame (space). that looks simple: (0, 0, 0), (0.3, 0, 0), (0.3, 0.1, 0), (0, 0.1, 0)... ok maybe with some offset because the marker's origin is at its *center*. then use cv::projectPoints using the marker's rvec,tvec and your 3d points

Comment: Hey,
yeah that worked really well. But not completely but i guess thats more programming issue maybe you can have a look on it: Problem is that point1 is displayed correctly but point2 and point3 are jumping around:

    `objpts = np.float32([[0,0,0], [0.1,0,0], [0.1,0.3,0], [0,0.3,0]]).reshape(-1,3)  
  
    imgpts , jac = cv2.projectPoints(objpts, rvec, tvec, k, d)  
  
    point1 = int(imgpts[1][0][0]), int(imgpts[1][0][1])  
    point2 = int(imgpts[2][0][0]), int(imgpts[2][0][1])  
    point3 = int(imgpts[3][0][0]), int(imgpts[3][0][1])`

Comment: jumping around, but generally close to expected, right? your marker is tiny and in the corner of the area. it's also not very flat (paper is warped). and you probably chose fast but inaccurate methods for edge refinement of aruco markers (rather those are defaults).

Comment: What other options are there for edge refinement? 

Guess the problem with the jumping points is the camera calibration guess its not that accurant. But i have another problem: 
When i get close with the camera to the marker so that the project points are out of the visible area. Than they appeare elsewhere. Is there an option to only show them when the camera is that far away that all points are visible? 

Thank you again <3

Comment: please remember to focus on one question per question, as outlined in [ask]. -- please show what you mean. I can try to imagine but my imagination needn't correspond to what you're actually talking about.